# "Post compile hook" in auctex

Tags: auctex

How can I make emacs execute a script every time when a latex-compilation (via auctex and latexmk) finished successfully? In particular I want to send a SIGHUP signal to mupdf to make it reload my pdf file.

I know that the sighup can be send when using latexmk from commandline with -pvc option and that in this case also a general post compile hook is supported (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299822/post-compile-hook-latexmk), however latexmk -pvc doesn't integrate well in auctex (https://github.com/tom-tan/auctex-latexmk/pull/11), so I am looking for an emacs way for a post compile hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions`, as the name suggests it can be used to run functions after the compilation finished successfully.  This is its docstring:

> Hook being run after TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt finished successfully. The
>   functions in this hook are run with the DVI/PDF output file given as
>   argument.  Using this hook can be useful for updating the viewer
>   automatically after re-compilation of the document.
>
> If you use an emacs-internal viewer such as `doc-view-mode` or
>   `pdf-view-mode`, add `TeX-revert-document-buffer` to this hook.